# jQuery Mobile transistions on individual elements pagebefore change and page change

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-transitions

So, I am using jQuery Mobile and I'd like to animate individual elements on a page change both before and after the change. I set transitions to "none" in jQuery moblie then try to add class to css3 animate individual elements. It works on pagechange, so when you go to a new page the transition on the elements appears, but pagebeforechange happens to quickly and the animation is lost. Is there a way to make the pagebeforechange function wait until the animation is done then go on to the next page? preventDefault(); stops the page from changing at all. I need like a call back or deferred obj or something? If I call changepage in pagebeforechange after the animation is done...the function runs recursively :(

```
transitions: function(){
 $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    $('.search_words li').addClass('animated flipInX');
 });

 $(document).bind( "pagechange", function( e, data ) {
    $('.search_words li').addClass('animated flipInX');
 });
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could try pageshow instead of pagebeforechange. Beaucse pageshow is fired before the pagechange event